# Elasticsearch dynamic mapping compared to Solr dynamic field

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

In Solr I can define a dynamic field and tie it to a particular data type. In the following example all fields in an indexed document ending with "dt" will be indexed as a long.
`<dynamicField name="*_dt" stored="true" indexed="true" type="long" multiValued="true"/>`

In ElasticSearch, knowing the name of the field, I can use the "properties" sub-node in "mappings" to index a field to a particular type.
`"properties": {
  "msh_datetimeofmessage_hl7_dt": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "YYYYMMddHHmmss"
   },`

I tried the following and attempted using a template, unsuccessfully.
`"properties": {
  "*_dt": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "YYYYMMddHHmmss"
   },`

Does ElasticSearch provide the same functionality as Solr as described above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also  stuck with exact same problem. Please let me know, if this problem is solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be looking for functionality provided by [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html). Unless I am mistaken, your mapping would look something like this (mostly borrowed from the linked page).

```
PUT /my_index
{
"mappings": {
    "my_type": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "my_date_template": {
                  "match":              "*_dt", 
                  "mapping": {
                      "type":           "date",
                      "format": "YYYYMMDDHHmmss"
                  }
            }}
        ]
}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also found this answer I should have updated my question! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! Glad you found a solution and weren't actually waiting for the several months this question has been up. It's good practice, I think, to post answers to the questions you ask, especially since it helps cement your understanding of the solution. At least that's my experience.